# "Break" a set of list items with an H2 using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, while-loop

I'm using **WordPress** to generate a list of posts.

The outputted HTML looks something like this:

```
<ul>
<!-- HERE -->
<li id="post-258" class="grid_6 convenience-stores" data-id="post-258">
    <h1><a href="/?p=258">Local Store #2</a></h1>
</li>
<li id="post-109" class="grid_6 convenience-stores" data-id="post-109">
    <h1><a href="/?p=109">Local Store #1</a></h1>
</li>    
<!-- HERE -->
<li id="post-107" class="grid_6 where-to-buy" data-id="post-107">
    <h1><a href="/?p=107">Supermarket #2</a></h1>
</li>
<li id="post-105" class="grid_6 where-to-buy" data-id="post-105">
    <h1><a href="/?p=105">Supermarket #1</a></h1>
</li>
</ul>
```

I use the following PHP code to generate this:

```
<?php

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

            $category = get_the_category();
            $class = $category[0]->slug;

            ?>

                <li data-id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="grid_6 <?php echo $class; ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('small');?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

You can see I have 2 different categories / HTML class names "**where-to-buy**" & "**convenience-stores**".

Now, what I would like to do is "break" the loop when the category changes.

So, at the point in the above HTML where I have marked `<!-- HERE -->`, I was hoping I could add an `<h2>` element to signify a heading for the next set of posts.

Is this possible?

And if so, how do I achieve this?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It would really improve the readability of the code if you would use functionnames like 'getId()' instead of 'the_ID()'

Comment: ^ Hey Dirk. Sorry, I'll get on to WordPress shortly about that - the rascals!! ;-)

Comment: is that really Wordpress style? Ouch... Excuse my comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of the previous value of `$class` (eg. `$prevClass`) and check against this in your loop. Presumably the records are already in `$class` order?

```
<?php
$prevClass = null;
while (have_posts()):
  the_post(); 

  $category = get_the_category();
  $class = $category[0]->slug;

  if ($class != $prevClass) {
    /* echo appropriate heading / li here */
    /* It needs to be contained in an LI here in order to be valid HTML */
    echo "<li><h2>$class</h2></li>";  // Change $class to appropriate heading
  }
?>

                <li data-id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="grid_6 <?php echo $class; ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('small');?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>

<?php
$prevClass = $class;
endwhile;
?>
```

Note, however, that with your current HTML markup it is not valid to simply output an `H2` in the places you have marked - these will need to be inside an `li`. Or, close and open the `ul`.

Having multiple `H1`s is not necessarily a good idea either, although several wordpress themes do seem to follow this structure. If you are using HTML5 and `article`/`section` then this might be OK. `H2`s might be more appropriate here.

Comment: You're right.
The more I think about it, the more I'm inclined to place an `h2` inside the `li` and actually perform the while loop inside the `li`.

Comment: Or it might be more appropriate to have multiple lists? Your `<!-- HERE -->` heading would then simply prefix each list.

Comment: Hi w3d, sadly the way this complicated AJAX works I don't think it would work with that.

Would it be too naughty (non-semantic) if I was just to add the `h2` in before the first `li` for that category? I wouldn't tell ;-)

I tried the solution you posted above but not sure how to add in the correct `h2`. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, managed to display correctly :-) -- Only slight issue now is the H2 disappears when I start clicking on the AJAX links. Time to investigate.

Comment: Now fixed. Placed inside `li`. Off to confession in a minute ;-) Thanks so much for your help, w3d.

Comment: Well you appear to have resolved it. To answer your earlier Q... If you were to place the `h2` directly before the `li` it would make the HTML invalid. If the HTML is invalid then its behaviour is undefined and could break in certain browsers. I also updated the code to include example output.